# How can I make a node setup, where only round emitter glows outside the image?

Tags: compositing-nodes, blur

How can I make a light source glow and that only this glow surrounds the emitter?

I tried the following compositor setups:
In this setup the emitter (white) is blurred, so that it glows outside the image. But, what I don't want, the red piece is also blurred to outside the image
[image]

In this setup, the red piece is not blurred, but the glow of the emitter (white) doesn't glow outside the image either.
[image]

How can I make a setup, where the emitter glows outside the image, but red piece doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

You could enable an emission pass in the render layers tab:

[image]

Then blur and overlay the Emit pass:

[image]

Comment: For the Emit Pass doesn't have alpha channel, you could use a Mix Node Add or Lighten and switch the inputs. Doing so, you can apply the effect even over image with a background.

Answer (score 1):

Use a *ColorRamp Node* to isolate the highlights

[image]

[image]

### NOTE

This is a common way to set the treshold of black and white area for creating a mask.

However, the answer of @ajwood is more specific to the question, because the glow effect is applied to materials that actually emit light.

Answer (score -1):

This selects by color and has colored alpha over.  In case you do not want to use white light objects and object id.  White ignored. Blue is selected and yellow is cast.

[image]

Nodes

[image]

Comment: in the first image the nodes are way too small to make sense of them. Can you edit and make them more readable?

Comment: The second image emphasizes the nodes with larger nodes. You may evaluate the second image.