# Low light emission color

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

I started a low light interior bar scene with an emission shader on some paper lanterns. If I set the strength to 1, the color of the lanterns look great but there's too much light in the scene. If I set the strength to 0.2 then the light levels in the room look great but the color of the lanterns look dull & grey. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I suggest adding a few pictures to illustrate your point.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Filmic Blender](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender/tree/master) set of Luts and OCIO configs that @Troy_s has been working on, to render images with a much wider dynamic range. 
Read this answer for a detailed description on how it works.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46940/1853