# Increasing Emission without Increasing Brightness

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, light, lighting

How would I go about increasing the strength/distance of an `Emission` texture without the texture getting brighter in Blender Cycles?

Lets say I take the following texture and make a light mask out of it. I then mix them equally with the Texture as a `Diffuse BSDF` and the Mask as an `Emission`.

[image: How the textures are mixed]

With the `Strength` set as `1.000` the texture looks ok but I feel it just isn't bright enough. But if I set it to something higher (like `100.000`) the texture gets oversaturated.

[image: Left image where the strength is 1.000. Right image where the strength is 100.000]

Is there some way I can have the light emit to infinity if I so pleased, yet have the texture remain the same brightness in Cycles?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow/43387 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Light Path input node Is Camera Ray socket as the factor to your Mix Shader node

[image]

This will result in the Emission being used for everything but the Camera (so it will be used for lighting the scene) and only the Diffuse Shader will be used when viewed direct from the camera.

Comment: Thank you. For a moment it looked like it was still brightening the texture, but realized it was the reflection from the floor. I added another "Emission Mask" so that I could individually control the brightness of the texture separate from the actual light.