# How to get candle flame

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

Using the fire simulation, I want to create a candle flame. What settings should I use for this? I'm bit confused: the flame goes up or gives extra fire. I'm getting a circular effect at the bottom and I need the effect in the reference image: pointed upward, and not circular at the base. What am I missing to get that small candle fire light effect?

[image]

[image]

I got this flame:

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4004" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4004/) here is your flame, you can play with the settings
huge effects on this type of fire have :
resolution
vorticities (0 = flat smoke stream)
disolve dont use smoker high resolution for this.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow

Comment: Looks good Thanks for sending the file. How can i control the height. I want the height of the flame should me low or less. Other than that its look perfect. So can u go in detail little how to control the height to make it shrink half of its original size for now. Thanks

Comment: on the outer side cube try the setting "smoke flames" speed.
that should mimic how fast the material burns, ea benzine vs wood

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101694/procedural-candlelight/101701#101701