# How to get rid of red/orange pixels?

Tags: rendering, interface

[image: GlassOrnament]
First, what causes the red/orange flecks and is there a way to get rid of them.
Second, I made a fire shader hopefully shown below.
A lot of first here:
First model (glass bowl), first node editor usage on all the materials.
[image: fire shader]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles

Comment: Please read the following link to understand what questions are off topic here. https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic. (number 6) I edited the title of your question to make it fit within the scope of the site. For feedback, suggestions and other subjective criteria you can post on the blenderartists.org forum, they have a section for critiques and work in progress. You can also take the [tour] to learn how to make better use of this site.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101694/procedural-candlelight