# How do I achieve an image lit by candle light?

Tags: materials, lighting

I've put together my best candle from following a youtube video.

But at the end, they just skip the lighting and show the picture, which means I have no idea what to do next!

Here's the final image they show:
[image]

And here's where I'm at in Blender 2.8:
[image]

Can anyone give me any pointers/help to get me to where it looks similar to the first picture?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cycles. You don't need much. If you are using cycles you can use an emitter shader as the flame, not much else, as the candle will light the scene.

Then read the following link:

[Make the flame of a candle more yellow](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow/43250#43250)

There are options there to use the compositor, to create materials that are brighter for the scene and less bright for the camera, as well as using color management to create a more realistic

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the lighting, you can just place a Point Lamp on top of the candle, change the Size and the Intensity of the Point Lamp to something lower, also Change the Lamp Color to Warm color