# How to create a fake fire/flame?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, smoke-simulation

I'm attempting to fake a couple flames on some candles. Since my scene is already pretty intensive, I think that doing a fire simulation would just add more to render times. Trying to use a transparent flame texture with some emission shaders but cant seem to get too good of a result. It ends up either looking too bright or not transparent enough. Here is in eevee (hdri was having issues so this is with just some sun lamps)

[image]

I tried adding some glow in the compositor but its not satisfactory. Is there any other way to fake fire? This is just a transparent image on a plane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a shader only solution, one way is a simple material such as the following:

[image]
<sup>*Click to enlarge*</sup>

[Blackbody Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/converter/blackbody.html#blackbody-node) is used for color.
See [kelvin color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) for some examples of values to start with. You can adjust these values up and down until you get something you like.

The [layer weight node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/layer_weight.html#layer-weight-node) is used for a mixing factor between the two blackbody nodes creating a result like below:

[image]

An approach like this should keep resources low and be fairly manageable. Note that also, the flame object is a quad-sphere modeled to a flame and not a flat plane.

Comment: Great answer! This works for me. A question though: Would I have to add another emission and blackbody shader to give the bottom a sort of blueish-hue? Also how could i add some waviness/transparency procedurally?

Comment: To give the bottom a sort of blueish-hue, use a gradient and a color ramp , Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43248/make-the-flame-of-a-candle-more-yellow

Comment: Oh, that's really clever :)